# How I can execute queries from a file one at a time

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

I have a big file containing some SQL queries that I need to run it on php. My project is written upon Laravel v5.6 hence I use the Laravel's `DB` Facade to run the sql queries locates in my sql file.

The code that runs the database queries is:

```
            $sqlFile=gzopen(__DIR__.'/../sql/queries.sql.gz','r');

            if($sqlFile==false){
                throw new \Exception('Failed to migrate the legacy database');
            }
            echo "Reading ".__DIR__.'/../sql/queries.sql.gz';
            $sql="";
            while (false !== $chunk = gzread($sqlFile, 1000)) {
                $sql.=$chunk;
            }

            gzclose($sqlFile);
            echo "Running Sql";
            DB::connection('etable')->unprepared($sql);
```

What I want to do is to "chunk" my `queries.sql.gz` in order to run the sql queries once at a time. Assume that queries can be rather complex such as:

```
select * from (
  select * from table1 where age >20
) as seniors JOIN
(
  select * from table1 where age <2
) as children on seniors.child_id=children.id;
```

So I want once I read a whole query from the file immediately to execute it in order to speed things up. But how do I detect whether a whole query has been read?

As you can see I run the whole file contents and then I execute the queries alltogether.

The gziped file has the following size:

```
ls -l ./database/sql
σύνολο 116
-rw-rw-r-- 1 pcmagas pcmagas 117868 Ιαν   9 11:10 test_etable.sql.gz
```

And once I run the piece of code above it takes more than 30 minutes to read it. The code itself will run on a migration script and I plan to run it on my CI/CD pipeline, therefore I want to run as fast as possible.

Comment: " how do I detect whether a whole query has been read"...you'd have to write a SQL parser, or near enough. Unless you add some other custom delimiter into the file which is not part of the SQL syntax, so that your code can understand it and split the text.

Comment: P.S. you mention wanting to "speed things up"...why do you expect this will speed anything up? How big is this zip file, how long does it take to read from it? And the queries do not execute asynchronously, so I think all you'll be doing here is changing the order of execution (i.e. "read one query, execute it, read next query, execute it", instead of "read all queries, execute all queries") rather than improving the performance of the overall script. So it might be slightly less time before the first query gets executed, sure, but overall I'm not sure you'll see any significant difference.

Comment: But in my case the slow part is reading all queries from the files due to its sheer size.

Comment: Ok well you didn't entirely make that clear. Just how big a file are we talking though? Exactly how slow is slow? What kind of change in performance would be considered acceptable, exactly? Please give us precise information, in case it would have any impact on potential solutions. Your proposed change might mean that some of the earlier queries will execute sooner, but overall it will still take the same amount of time to complete the whole file, I think.

Comment: What's the reason you're using gzread with just a thousand bytes if it's a huge file? Did you try to split that file?

Comment: @Seth No I did not try to do that. Actually the sql file is a dump from my current database, that is rather huge. The size is big even after I deleted first the unwanted data in order to keep it minimal as possible.

Comment: It looks to me that what you're trying to accomplish might be better run as a stored procedure on your database and then simply call that from your script.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need a combination of python and php. With the python you need to "chunk" the file into smaller single-query ones whilst in php you just scan the directory for the files and execute them by order.

For the python part you just need the library `sqlparse` and the following script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import sqlparse
import gzip
import os 

file='/home/pcmagas/Kwdikas/etable-api/database/sql/myapp.sql.gz'
dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(file))

file_handler=gzip.open(file,'r')
sql=file_handler.read()
queries=sqlparse.split(sql)

i=1;
for query in queries:
    file=open(dir_path+'_'+str(i)+'_'+'myapp_migration.sql','w')
    file.write(query)
    file.close()
    i+=1
```

Then you need to iterate via php's `scandir()` then read the file contents one by one, and then execute each query one by one.